# No iOS Distribution certificate was found

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I keep getting this message when I refresh under Xcode organizer when it is "Checking for pending CSR..."

```
No iOS Distribution Certificate Found

No iOS Distribution certificate was found. However, there is already a 
certificate request pending. An Agent or Admin must approve this request 
before you can download your certificate.
```

I'm using Xcode 4.6.1. There are no certificates in the portal and no pending ones.

Thanks!

Comment: Contact Apple Developer Program support, they will walk you through the process of getting it fixed. See [my answer over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17373053/93921).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the message says it all. The cert that you requested is pending for approval. You can wait until it gets approved and download it or let xcode sync it. Option two revoke that and create another one in case the one pending does get hanging for too long.

Comment: I'm the Admin and Agent. There isn't any pending certificates in the portal and no certificates there too.

Comment: I know. There has been something requiring that which in your case is not necessary. Just revoke the cert pending and issue a new one. That should take care of your problem.

Comment: Where do I find this cert to revoke?

Comment: In Dev site in provisioning tab. It should be listed under name you set for it. The status should show pending for approval.

Comment: Hmm. But I have 0 certificates and 0 provisioning profiles in the portal. None of them are pending for approval.

Comment: Then try to request a new one and get that one approved. If the pending cert shows up later revoke and delete it. But I doubt it will show up since it may have fallen through the cracks. The new one should kick in and be good to go.

Comment: That did the trick. I had to create a new distribution profile + certificate.

Comment: With this, I even managed to fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896986/restore-ios-team-provisioning-profile . The managed profile was created back and was available in the portal and organizer.

Comment: Would you like me to place an answer on that question so you can accept that one as well?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to download the certificate from the portal and add it to your keychain. If there are no certificates in the portal, then you'll need to create one and upload it. Follow the instructions in the portal for this.

Comment: there is no cert in the portal, it has been approved yet.