# Restore iOS Team Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I deleted the default Xcode managed "iOS Team Provisioning Profile". I couldn't get it to work because of "Valid signing identify not found" even thought I have generated a new certificate and is available under my KeyChain.

Even after I revoke all certificates, the number of certificates is still wrong.

```
Name: iOS Team Provisioning Profile: iOS Wildcard AppID
Type: Development
App ID: Xcode: iOS Wildcard AppID (*)
Certificates: 3 total
Devices: 10 total
Enabled Services: None
Expires: Mar 21, 2014
Status: Active (Managed by Xcode)
```

How can I bring this back?

Do I have to create a new one but it will no longer be managed? I have to add new devices/certificates manually next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to delete the Dev profile and create a new one then refresh it through organizer or download it and sync it with xcode.

Comment: Do you mean the Developer Profile that we can find under "certificates" ?

Comment: @MatterGoal, in the case of above question yes. In xcode.

Comment: I meant to say "certificates" in the developer portal. Where I can find this section in xCode?

Comment: @MatterGoal, here is the link. It prompts you to login. https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action

Answer (score 2):

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16896752/1223386

The trick was to delete away everything and create a distribution profile and certificate.

Use the organizer to refresh and it will be created back.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have your iOS Team profile listed as active in the online Dev Center provisioning portal, download it and double-click it. This will re-install it in XCode.