# Restore iOS Team Provisioning Profile (Xcode 5)

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program

I've already read this answer but I think that it is old [Restore iOS Team Provisioning Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896986/restore-ios-team-provisioning-profile).

I've accidentally deleted my iOS Team Provisioning Profile (I was invited to an Account of type "Company").

How can I restore it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you found in this situation you can easily restore the certificate just following these steps:

From Xcode:
**1)** Preferences

**2)** Tab Accounts

**3)** select the account you want to restore

**4)** click over "View Detail"

**5)** click the arrow at the bottom-left corner

Now you should see under provisioning profiles column the profile correctly restored and if you open the Developer Portal page you should see the restored profile.