# No iOS Development certificate was found.

Tags: xcode, certificate, admin

I used xcode in 2010, I have removed every certificate that I can find on developer.apple.com and from in keychain so I can have a fresh start.

When I click on provisioning refresh button I get the error message:

> No iOS Development certificate was found. However, there is already a certificate request pending. An Agent or Admin must approve this request before you can download your certificate.

I have logged in and out, started and restarted Xcode.

I am the sole developer, so am the admin who would approve certificates, there are none. None at all.

None listed under All / Pending / Development / Distribution.

Will Apple not let me start anew?

Comment: Brilliant video on youtube. by excellent easy.

The link is; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6wHeh0f5vQ

Search for xcode excellent easy.

Comment: I have the same problem ... nothing pending so nothing to approve!

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem you had.

I removed all certificates from developer.apple.com and from my keychain

When i went to https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/
I was always creating only the Adhoc certificate, I was missing the 
"iOS App Development Certificate".

As soon as I created the "iOS App Development Certificate", xcode stopped with this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Apple Developer Program support, they will walk your through the process of fixing it. See [my answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373053/93921).