# Xcode: No Dev Certificate found, but they are present in my developer account

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

When I refresh my Organizer I get the

`No iOS Development certificate was found. However, there is already a certificate request pending. An Agent or Admin must approve this request before you can download your certificate.`

message.

I login to my devloper account and check out the certificate - its seems fine (ie not expired). I then check out the pending section - but there isnt any there to approve.

I then download the Certificate that is associated with my apps provision profile, install it on KeyChain by double clicking it and try to refresh Organizer again. But still get the same error.

Am I missing a step here at all? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Contact Apple Developer Program support, they will walk you through the process of getting it fixed. See [my answer over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17373053/93921).

Answer (score 0):

Just **revoke** your certificate from your developer account then create certificate again.

This is because, present certificate is associate with other system's CSR(CertificateSigningRequest). So either get export certificate(.p12) of present certificate (just install certificate from which it was created, right click and then export will give you cer.p12 and it will run on you other system ) or just **revoke** and create againg.

Comment: Thanks. Tried to revoke and create again, but I still have the same issue

Comment: can you put screenshot of keyChain

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access into itunesconnect.apple.com ?

It seems, your certificate is Entering in Corporation Team. And Admin of corporation must enter to developer.apple.com and click **Approve** on your certificate request.

And you can download your certificate and install him. Provision file it seems is exist.

Comment: Thanks but I dont see where to approve the certificate on either developer.apple or iTunes Connect. On iTunes Connect the certificate appears in the Production list already, not the Pending list.

Comment: @MeltingDog Your developer account is registered how indie developer or how team developer?